# pandas extract regex allowing mismatches

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, extract, fuzzy-search

Pandas has a very fast and nice string method, extract(). This method works perfectly with a regex such as this one:

`strict_pattern = r"^(?P<pre_spacer>ACGAG)(?P<UMI>.{9,13})(?P<post_spacer>TGGAGTCT)"`

```
test_df

    R1
21  ACGAGTTTTCGTATTTTTGGAGTCTTGTGG
22  ACGAGTAGGGAGGGGGGTGGAGTCTCAGCG
23  ACGAGGGGGGGGAGGCTGGAGTCTCCGGGT
24  ACGAGAATAACGTTTGGTGGAGTCTACCAC
25  ACGAGGGGAATAAATATTGGAGTCTCCTCC
26  ACGAGATTGGGTATGCTGGAGTCTCTGTTC
27  ACGAGGTACCCGCGCCATGGAGTCTCTCTG
28  ACGAGTGGTTTTTGTCGTGGAGTCTCACCA
29  ACGAGACGTGTCCACCATGGAGTCTTGTCT
```

```
test_df.R1.str.extract(strict_pattern)

    pre_spacer  UMI     post_spacer
21  ACGAG   TTTTCGTATTTT    TGGAGTCT
22  ACGAG   TAGGGAGGGGGG    TGGAGTCT
23  ACGAG   GGGGGGGAGGC     TGGAGTCT
24  ACGAG   AATAACGTTTGG    TGGAGTCT
25  ACGAG   GGGAATAAATAT    TGGAGTCT
26  ACGAG   ATTGGGTATGC     TGGAGTCT
27  ACGAG   GTACCCGCGCCA    TGGAGTCT
28  ACGAG   TGGTTTTTGTCG    TGGAGTCT
29  ACGAG   ACGTGTCCACCA    TGGAGTCT
```

But as it is not using the `regex` package but `re` (if I'm not wrong), it does not support the usage of a regex which allows mismatches. Such as this one:

`lax_pattern = r"^(?P<pre_spacer>ACGAG){s<=1}(?P<UMI>.{9,13})(?P<post_spacer>TGGAGTCT){s<=1}"`

This regex allows one substitution in the pre_spacer and post_spacer sequences.

As shown in this example, the `regex` package allows this kind of regex:

```
seq = 'ACGAGCGCCCACCCGCCTGGAGTCTACCAACGGTAACAGCTG'
lax_pattern = r"^(?P<pre_spacer>ACGAG){s<=1}(?P<UMI>.{9,13})(?P<post_spacer>TGGAGTCT){s<=1}"
m = regex.match(lax_pattern,seq)
m.groupdict()

{'pre_spacer': 'ACGAG', 'UMI': 'CGCCCACCCGCC', 'post_spacer': 'TGGAGTCT'}
```

What I would like is to make extract() compatible with this kind of regex, or any fast workaround.

I have done this but is 12 times slower than extract and I deal with very big dataframes.

```
def extract_regex(pattern, seq):
    m = regex.match(pattern,seq)
    try:
        d=m.groupdict()
        return list(d.values())
    except AttributeError:
        return [np.nan]*3

test_df["pre_spacer"],test_df["UMI"],test_df["post_spacer"] = zip(*test_df.apply(lambda row: extract_regex(lax_pattern,row.R1) ,axis=1))

test_df

    R1  pre_spacer  UMI     post_spacer
21  ACGAGTTTTCGTATTTTTGGAGTCTTGTGG  ACGAG   TTTTCGTATTTT    TGGAGTCT
22  ACGAGTAGGGAGGGGGGTGGAGTCTCAGCG  ACGAG   TAGGGAGGGGGG    TGGAGTCT
23  ACGAGGGGGGGGAGGCTGGAGTCTCCGGGT  ACGAG   GGGGGGGAGGC     TGGAGTCT
24  ACGAGAATAACGTTTGGTGGAGTCTACCAC  ACGAG   AATAACGTTTGG    TGGAGTCT
25  ACGAGGGGAATAAATATTGGAGTCTCCTCC  ACGAG   GGGAATAAATAT    TGGAGTCT
26  ACGAGATTGGGTATGCTGGAGTCTCTGTTC  ACGAG   ATTGGGTATGC     TGGAGTCT
27  ACGAGGTACCCGCGCCATGGAGTCTCTCTG  ACGAG   GTACCCGCGCCA    TGGAGTCT
28  ACGAGTGGTTTTTGTCGTGGAGTCTCACCA  ACGAG   TGGTTTTTGTCG    TGGAGTCT
29  ACGAGACGTGTCCACCATGGAGTCTTGTCT  ACGAG   ACGTGTCCACCA    TGGAGTCT
```

Any ideas of how to tune the pandas `extract()` method or to provide the desired function with a similar speed?

Thanks in advance!

Pau.

Comment: As the matter of fact, `.str` access is not always faster than a simple `for` loop. I bet something like `pd.DataFrame([extract_regex(lax_pattern,row.R1) for row in df.T])` would be faster than `.str.extract()`.

Answer (score 1):

Until `pandas` is compiled with the `regex` library, you can't use these features in `.extract`.

You will probably have to rely on `.apply` with a custom method:

```
import regex
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({"R1": ['ACGAGTTTTCGTATTTTTGGAGTCTTGTGG', 'AAAAGGGA']})

lax_pattern = regex.compile(r"^(?P<pre_spacer>ACGAG){s<=1}(?P<UMI>.{9,13})(?P<post_spacer>TGGAGTCT){s<=1}")

empty_val = pd.Series(["","",""], index=['pre_spacer','UMI','post_spacer'])

def extract_regex(seq):
    m = lax_pattern.search(seq)
    if m:
        return pd.Series(list(m.groupdict().values()), index=['pre_spacer','UMI','post_spacer']) #  list(m.groupdict().values())
    else:
        return empty_val


test_df[["pre_spacer","UMI","post_spacer"]] = test_df['R1'].apply(extract_regex)
```

Output:

```
>>> test_df
                               R1 pre_spacer           UMI post_spacer
0  ACGAGTTTTCGTATTTTTGGAGTCTTGTGG      ACGAG  TTTTCGTATTTT    TGGAGTCT
1                        AAAAGGGA
```