# How to extract certain values from a string based on prefix in Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas data frame where each value is a long text string of text. Somewhere in that text I may or may not have an object number with a certain prefix ("IFL" or "IFN") that I need to extract and add as it's own column.

Data looks like:

```
Description
12753, IFL12329-1, Supply Chain, (May)
120873, [send], 7385876, (June), IFN1228-3
```

Intended Result:

```
Description                                     Object Number
12753, IFL12329-1, Supply Chain, (May)          IFL12329-1
120873, [send], 7385876, (June), IFN1228-3      IFN1228-3
```

The prefix has to be included in the new column and what makes it difficult is the fact that it's two different prefix conditions and they're in different positions each time (sometimes in the middle of the string, other times at the end).

Comment: Can you print `df.head.to_dict()`. With a column like that it's difficult to reproduce

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas extract regex allowing mismatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921051/pandas-extract-regex-allowing-mismatches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a regex with `str.extract`

```
df['object']= df['Description'].str.extract('((IFN|IFL)\d+-\d)')[0]

print(df)


                                  Description      object
0      12753, IFL12329-1, Supply Chain, (May)  IFL12329-1
1  120873, [send], 7385876, (June), IFN1228-3   IFN1228-3
```

Comment: It can also be ``(IF\w\d+-\d+)``

Comment: This works, much appreciated!